# Определение нового участника pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграм бота с использованием pyTelegramBotAPI для группы. Т.к в этом я полный чайник буду задавать вопросы (может много)

Как боту понять что новый участник зашел в группу и отправил соответствующие сообщение с приветствием?

Comment: А как быть, если бот не видит события о входе нового пользователя?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
    def handler_new_member(message):
        user_name = message.new_chat_member.first_name
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро пожаловать, {user_name}!")
```

Comment: Сам нашел) Молодец! :)

Comment: А не подскажете как мне выводить first_name і last_name в одном сообщении?

Comment: Не можешь сделать типа
`member = message.new_chat_member; fullname = f'{member.first_name} {member.last_name}' -> f'Добро пожаловать, {fullname}'`